# Laravel how to make all controller returned data as json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, backend

How can I make my controllers that it's returned data is a json by not repeating my code.

**Sample Controller**

```
public function getTeams(Request $request){
    $result = Team::where('competitionId',$request->input('competitionId',9224))
        ->orderBy('teamName')    
        ->get(['teamId as id','teamName as name']);
    return response($result, 200)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

public function getTeamStats(Request $request) {
    if($request->id){
        $result = TeamCompetitionStatistics::getTeamStats($request->id);
        return response($result, 200)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}
```

as you can see I have repeated this section twice

```
return response($result, 200)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Is their a way to do this in much better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Trait, which you will include in every controller that needs to reuse certain logic. You could abstract those lines in a function inside the trait like so:

```
trait MyResponseTrait{

    public function successfulResponse($result)
    {
      return response($result, 200)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}
```

And your code will look like this:

```
public function getTeams(Request $request){
    $result = Team::where('competitionId',$request->input('competitionId',9224))
        ->orderBy('teamName')    
        ->get(['teamId as id','teamName as name']);
    return successfulResponse($result);
}

public function getTeamStats(Request $request) {
    if($request->id){
        $result = TeamCompetitionStatistics::getTeamStats($request->id);
        return successfulResponse($result)

    }
}
```

Note that you will have to include the Trait inside your Controller, for example:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use MyResponseTrait;
    // Will be able to call successfulResponse() inside here...
}
```

More on [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)...

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 3):

Laravel includes a JSON response but Laravel 5.4 will also output JSON if you just return the collection.

The JSON response doc:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses

**JSON Responses**

The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to application/json, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the json_encode PHP function:

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

If you would like to create a JSONP response, you may use the json method in combination with the withCallback method:

```
return response()
        ->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
        ->withCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

---

Beyond that, an easy way to perform repeated logic is to extract it to a method in the base controller class.